# How do I find out whats causing my to css to be struck-through in chrome?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, heroku

My app works fine on local but when I deploy it onto heroku some of the CSS is showing as struck-through on chrome how do I find out what is overriding my 
styling?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the heroku app?

Comment: I would take a look at the Chrome devtools console. You have several errors there that could be causing your issue.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention you need to go on the http:// link on that there is no errors on the console but still some of my styling is struck through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you scroll down the inspector, you will most likely find more than one of the same attributes (i.e: 2 different font declarations). The struck out won't be applied and will be overridden (possibly either be your CSS file's ordering or JS overriding it). look through inspector and filter by the name of the attribute that is struck out. This will then tell you what is overriding it:
[image]
then clicked on the file name in the top right corner and it will highlight the line the css is on. You can use this information to determine what is causing your css to be "stuck out". To fix this: try and avoid declaring multiple attributes for the same thing (i.e don't set text size of the same thing in two different places); Make use of classes and IDs to make it easier to set attributes for different  elements (ID will always take precedence over class); If you cant avoid using duplicate attributes (for example if an external style sheet you cant change is applying styles make sure the attribute you want to be applied is declared after the ones currently being applied as CSS will use the attribute read last (i.e if you set the background to orange in one place but then further down your code set it as green it will be green). alternatively, as a last resort you can use The `!important` exception, which will overwrite any other declarations. However, this is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.(reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you!  Although I couldn't find out what was overriding, I was able to use !important to bypass this

Comment: Remember "!important" is a _tricky hack_. A proper CSS code should be "a cascade".